# Why does it give an error "missing required parameters: id"?

Tags: yii2

I understand that the error occurred due to the confusion of variables, although these are my assumptions .. The fact is that this error occurred in the update and in the view: update and view. I have already tried everything .. Please poke your nose where I went wrong?

My controller in which I pass two actions view and update:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    return $this->render('view', [
        'faq' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}

public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $faq = FaqLang::findOne($id);
    $faqLang = Faq::findOne($faq->faq_id);

    if ($faq->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $faqLang->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple([$faq, $faqLang]))
    {
        $faqLang->save(false);
        $faq->save(false);

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $faq->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'faq' => $faq,
        'faqLang' => $faqLang,
    ]);
}

protected function findModel($id)
{
    if (($faq = FaqLang::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $faq;
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
}
```

view.php in which I am trying to display data using DetailView

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $faqLang app\modules\admin\models\Faq */
/* @var $faq app\modules\admin\models\FaqLang */

//$this->title = $faq->id;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Faqs'), 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="faq-view">

<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

<p>
    <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['update', 'id' => $faq->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Delete'), ['delete', 'id' => $faq->id], [
        'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
        'data' => [
            'confirm' => Yii::t('app', 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?'),
            'method' => 'post',
        ],
    ]) ?>
</p>

<?= DetailView::widget([
    'faq' => $faq,
    'attributes' => [
        'id',
        ['attribute' => 'name', 'value' => 'faqLang.name'],
        ['attribute' => 'body', 'value' => 'faqLang.body:ntext'],
        'put_date',
        [
            'attribute' => 'hide',
            'format' => 'html',
            'value' => function($model) {
                if($model->hide == 'show')
                    return 'Нет';
                else
                    return 'Да';
            }
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

update.php through which the records are updated

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $faqLang app\modules\admin\models\Faq */
/* @var $faq app\modules\admin\models\FaqLang */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Update Faq: ' . $faq->id, [
    'nameAttribute' => '' . $faq->id,
]);
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Faqs'), 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => $faq->id, 'url' => ['view', 'id' => $faq->id]];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = Yii::t('app', 'Update');
?>
<div class="faq-update">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= $this->render('_form', [
        'faq' => $faq,
        'faqLang' => $faqLang,
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

And 2 related Faq and FaqLang models
Faq.php

```
public function getFaqLang()
{
    return $this->hasMany(FaqLang::className(), ['faq_id' => 'id']);
}
```

FaqLang.php

```
public function getFaq()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Faq::className(), ['id' => 'faq_id']);
}
```

Comment: show your error, or a section from runtime app.log at the time when you tried to access this actions

Comment: What is your url structure?

Comment: @vvpanchev Hello url structure: admin/faqs/update

Comment: Hello my log: https://dropmefiles.com/qXAot

Comment: @vvpanchev I understood my mistake based on your questions ..

But now when passing admin / faqs / update? Id = 1
Another error occured:

Call to a member function formName () on null

Comment: Your object is null. Passed id must be primary key of your main table - faq. First you find faq, after that you find lang object... in your case you find first faqLang, but if you pass primary key of faq, you must search by faq_id column in faqLang

Answer (score 0):

You may be seeing this error because the request path/query string you're using to run your controller actions does not include the `$id` parameter.

If you specify a method parameter in a controller action, that parameter must be defined in your routes, and passed in the request

Your action methods are as follows:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    ....
}
```

Which expects a route like

```
'/view/<id:\d+>' => 'admin/faqs/view'
```

and

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    ...
}
```

Which expects a route like

```
'/update/<id:\d+>' => 'admin/faqs/update'
```

So for example, for the request `/view/123` , the value `123` is passed as the value of `$id` into the `actionView($id)` method.

If you have a route set up like

```
'/view' => 'admin/faqs/view'
```

There's no `id` parameter defined, and the controller will throw the error `missing required parameters: id`